# Ping not working for a pattern in python

Tags: python

I have a series of ips which I need to check via ping. ping contains pattern like :

```
 ping -c 3 -p abc0000114a 10.65.200.44
```

In this, `'abc'` is constant, `0000114a` and `10.65.200.44` are variables. I'm using the following code:

```
address = "abc"+str(formatted)+ " " + ''.join(map(str, ip))

res = subprocess.call(['ping','-c', '3', '-p', address])
if res == 0:
     print "ping to", address, "OK"
elif res == 2:
     print "no response from", address
else:
     print "ping to", address, "failed!"
```

It is not working, as in subprocess, variable 'address' is not an ip, infact, it is a pattern

O/p:

```
 usage: ping [-AaDdfnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-G sweepmaxsize] [-g sweepminsize]
            [-h sweepincrsize] [-i wait] [-l preload] [-M mask | time] [-m ttl]
            [-P policy] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr] [-s packetsize] [-t timeout]
            [-W waittime] [-z tos] host
       ping [-AaDdfLnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-I iface] [-i wait] [-l preload]
            [-M mask | time] [-m ttl] [-P policy] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr]
            [-s packetsize] [-T ttl] [-t timeout] [-W waittime]
            [-z tos] mcast-group
ping to abc00001060 10.65.200.44 failed!
```

Whereas, it works:
~> `ping -c 3 -p abc0000114a 10.65.200.44`

```
PATTERN: 0xabc0000114a

PING 10.65.200.44 (10.65.200.44): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.65.200.44: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=12.925 ms
64 bytes from 10.65.200.44: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.300 ms
64 bytes from 10.65.200.44: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.207 ms

--- 10.65.200.44 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.207/4.477/12.925/5.974 ms
```

Comment: You have to pass the pattern and the ip as seperate arguments to `call`. Don't join them.

Comment: It is required to join them. I need this to work in script
ping -c 3 -p abc0000114a 10.65.200.44

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cmds = ['ping','-c', '3', '-p'].extend(address.split())
res = subprocess.call(cmds)
```

Comment: res = subprocess.call(cmds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1122, in _execute_child
    args = list(args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @user7994925 It seems the variable address is not a string. Can you explain map(str, ip)? what's the value of formatted and ip?

Comment: Thank you everyone. res = subprocess.call(shlex.split('ping -c 3 -p ' + address)) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

use shlex:

```
import shlex

res = subprocess.call(shlex.split('ping -c 3 -p ' + address))
```